# grab output variable SSIS package

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

I have a .NET application that executes an SSIS package.

At the end I have a script variable that assigns value X to a variable and then the package ends.

I need a way to grab the value of that variable from my .NET package. Can it be done?

The workflow is:

`.NET app > typical .NET stuff > execute SSIS package > SSIS package has a variable named "chicken" with value = 3 > .NET package continues and to do so it needs "chicken" value.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have used sql server deployment method for SSIS packages. Go through the below sample steps to read value from variable or set value of variable:

1. Import following assemblies to your application

   ```
   System.Data.SqlTypes;
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent;
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
   System.Data.SqlClient;
   ```
2. Add following segment of code which will return collection of SSIS packages deployed on SQL Server

   ```
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

   PackageInfos pInfos = app.GetPackageInfos("\\", ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ServerIp"].ToString(), "", "");
   ```

NOTE: `ServerIp` is subjected to SQL Server IP address

3. Now we will add package info (here name of SSIS Package) to drop down list, so that user can select SSIS package and execute the same.

   ```
   foreach (PackageInfo pInfo in pInfos)
       {

   if (pInfo.Name != "Maintenance Plans")
               ComboBoxJob.Items.Add(pInfo.Name);

       }
   ```
4. Following code segment shows you how to execute package. This code segment will get invoked when user will click “Execute” button shown at screen shots.

   ```
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
   app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

   DTSExecResult pkgResults_Sql;

   Package pkgIn = new Package();

   pkgIn = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\\"+ComboBoxJob.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(),ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ServerIp"].ToString(), "", "", null);


   // This statement set “Test” variable to 12


   pkg.Variables["Test"].Value = 12; 



   //This statement gets activity present at index 2 in SSIS package and 
   //allows you to modify properties. For example I am disabling activity 
   //present at index 2. So that when this package will execute activity at 
   //index 2 won’t be running 



   TaskHost th=(TaskHost)pkgIn.Executables[2];

   th.Disable =true;
   pkgResults_Sql = pkgIn.Execute();

   //Message box will show either Success/Failure

   MessageBox.Show(pkgResults_Sql.ToString());
   ```
5. For performing the entire functionality user must have respective permission on MSDB database.

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15868/Access-SSIS-package-activities-and-variable-throug)